# How to solve maven install error: cannot find symbol?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I've developed spring boot microservices that are responsible for user authentication and authorization. Now, as a final step, I want to dockerize those microservices. To do this, I need each microservice have its target folder with jar file.
In order to do this, I use maven clean, and then maven install in my ide. For all the microservices it works fine, except of identity-service. So, there is microservice amqp (message queue), that is responsible for rabbit mq config as well as publishing messages. The identity-service (currently the only one), uses amqp class RabbitMQMessageProducer to publish message. In its pom file, there is a dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tradebit</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

So, everything works fine, identity-service successfully interacts with amqp, messages are published, no errors etc. But, when I run maven install, I am getting an error [cannot find symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWaAe.png). So, it is likely not recognizing amqp dependency or idk.
[Amqp target folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmq3v.png) is as on the screenshot.

I tried to reimport the dependencies, several times performed clean install for both amqp and identity services. The problem remains.

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate the cache in IntelliJ IDEA yet ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa, yes, the same situation.

Comment: Also could you check if Java version is the same declared in maven one and what your IntelliJ IDEA use

Comment: and if it is compatible with new dependency that you imported

Comment: @AndreiLisa, java version is 17. Maven plugin version is 3.1.4. I am using ultimate edition. Regarding the compatibility, how to check it? In fact, other microservices were successfully installed with maven, so can it be the problem with versions?

Comment: I think you have a problem with configuration, recheck all one more time and that is all.

Comment: Also could you provide a simple reproductive example ? I am going to check if you will not be able to deal with it

Comment: @AndreiLisa, actually, I can give you an access to github repository, so you will be able to check it, because its a bit difficult to create a simple example that will describe my situation.

Comment: agree, let’s see it.

Comment: since it's a snapshot dependency, you could try updating those: mvn -U clean install

Comment: @AndreiLisa, how can I add you? Maybe we can contact somewhere else?

Comment: @wemu, I tried it, the same problem. Its like not recognizing amqp package when installing with maven

Comment: Just put GitHub link to the project here in comments

Comment: @AndreiLisa, here it is: https://github.com/bodyakyryliuk/TradeBit/tree/oauth2 . Please use oauth2 branch

Comment: I am going to look at your problem and also will give a solution

Comment: I wrote an answer, can you check it ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa, yees, it works! Thanks a lot. I was not able to check it erlier as I was at university.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could guess that `amqp` module is a common one and based on it and also on project structure/ idea, as a fix to solve this problem when is talking about `compile` phase on `mvn install` command.

On `amqp` module in `pom.xml` file at the end of file add next one build plugin:

```
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>rabbit-common</classifier>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/ApiGatewayApplication*</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

It just will create another `.jar` for module where is going to exclude `Main Class`.

Also in `identity-service` you will have to do declare `amqp` dependency as next one:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.tradebit</groupId>
        <artifactId>amqp</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <classifier>rabbit-common</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

It is going to fix the problem on compile time.

Also how I know maven doesn't allow dependency from executable `jar.` The `amqp` module is an executable Spring Boot application.